# File is open and doesn't load in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm trying to load an xlsx list, but a file is open and doesn't load in R.

Code:

```
dados_pp_master[[i]] <- data.frame(read_excel(arquivo_caracter[i], sheet = "PP Master",skip = 1, .name_repair = "minimal")
```

Log:

```
Error: Evaluation error: zip file 'V:/file/~$Schedule_3.xlsx' cannot be opened.
```

Is there any way to load an open xlsx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `~$` at beginning of your file path implies that you are only working with a cached version of the changes? I'm pretty sure you cannot open this specific file with Excel itself, simply because it is not a "normal" excel file. The error message in that context makes a lot of sense then.

Comment: is there any way to get the data that is not in that cache? What was already saved.

Comment: Is the actual file there? Can you open `Schedule_3.xlsx` with Excel or any editor? If so then it's just the wrong file path.

Comment: the file clicks, I can open it. The problem is that it is a file that is usually open, so when I try to load it it gives this error. I need to be able to load it even if it is open.